# Resizing remoted image(carrierwave)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, omniauth, carrierwave

I use `carrierwave` and `omniauth`(and `omniauth-facebook`) gems in my app. I think it makes no sense to describe how I use these gems. I get image from `request.env["omniauth.auth]` and save it to `@user.remote_avatar_url`. How I can resize this image before saving to db? Or remote image use only original size from source(facebook)?

Comment: you can't resize image, because omniauth only save url image into database, but you can config on view image , example : `<%= image_tag image_url(comment.user), "style" =>"width:50px;height:50px;" %>`

ref : [this](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook#image_size) and [here](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook#configuring)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer.

All what I needed its use `AvatarUploader` for `user` model.
Field `@user.avatar` was filled and image was resized automatically. And then I can use `@user.avatar_url(:thumb)`<--(for example).